# Error when installing Symfony2 - "no route found"

Tags: symfony, routes

I try to learn Symfony2 for a personnal project. 
I use Linux Ubuntu & Mac Os X Yosemite.

I installed the framework and created a new project on those two OS.

But when i go on my project i have a 404 error message.

For more information i use app8dev.php and i find this message:

> No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/my_project/web/")
>
> 1. in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2059

And my Log show me this route error

> 1. ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/my_project/web/")" at /var/www/html/my_project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2059

I have this problem on my two Os, someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just created a new Symfony project you will need to setup a controller and routes. See this web page for simple explanation of setting up new controllers:

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

If you have already setup a controller and route but it is not working you can view all registered routes in your application by running the command:

```
app/console router:debug
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was trying to follow this symfony2 tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Someone says me that is a normal error in Symfony 2.7. Because the bundle demo is not provided since Symfony 2.6.

Can someone confirm me this explanation ?